# Space between logical operators in c

Tags: c, optimization

I am registered on a online judge web, where there are different problems with predefined tests to calculate the time of the execution.

I have submitted the same code twice but with one difference:

```
if(x1 < x2 || y1 < y2)
//code
```

And the second submit:

```
if(x1 < x2 ||y1 < y2)
//code
```

As you can see in the second submit I don't have a space between `||` and `y1` and my result in time was:

- First submit: 0052
- Second submit: 006

How is it possible that I get a lower time in the first submit? The code is the same, the only change is a space.

**Edit:** The judge uses "gcc" compiler and the tests are always the same.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the space. At all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These two code snippets will produce exactly the same executable, so the whitespace is inconsequential. The only place it **might** have any impact is the compile time (as there's one byte less to parse), but I'd be **extremely** surprised if its noticible.

With such a short runtime, any number of environmental variables could skew the results - a temporary memory load, a certain page being swapped to disk at the wrong moment, you name it. Bottom line - this is probably a bad benchmark. This program should be executed a gazilion times and the averages compared. Executing it once gives **way** too much weight to uninteresting noise.

Answer (score 5):

Whitespace is irrelevant in C (and in most other languages). In any decent compiler the two versions will generate exactly the same machine language instruction output.

The difference in speed depends on some randomness of the measure, not on the spacing.

To get faster code you need to think to a better algorithm or, if the abstract algorithm is already optimal, to issues like cache coherence.

Answer (score 5):

White spaces are inconsequential in most of the programming languages.
In practical applications, the execution/compile time is dependent on the algorithm you use rather than white spaces.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, whitespace is inconsequential and will not result in any significant latency. Instead of concluding the same from one set of data, check for multiple execution, say 10 to see the difference.
The difference could also be a result from the server side where the code is being compiled since the state of the server may not be same during both execution.

Answer (score 0):

THE TIME OF EXECUTION WOULD DEPEND ON
1) The speed of the computer
2) The efficiency of the code.(logic)

Even if the logic is same every time you run a program its execution time would be different.